# How many button shapes can Access conceivably draw? (button next to each record on a continuous form)

Tags: forms, ms-access, button, vba

I have a continuous forms in Microsoft Access 2013 with button next to each record that will allow the user to open a link to the document.

It looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUeNs.png

Design view looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPOiz.png

It works great exactly as I want. My question is "Is this bad practice?"

This form could possibly have thousands of records. Is drawing that many buttons potentially a problem?

Comment: Couldn't you just use the "DblClick" event to open the link when the user double clicks on the item in the form?

Comment: @OpiesDad Yes, and I just found the "Is Hyperlink" property, so it pretty much solves this problem. But there are situations I still might want a button next to each record.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any issue with adding that number of controls. But that is a lot to show the user. At some point looking though all those would be inconvenient. Maybe you can give them some sort of filter that would narrow down what is presented to them.